# What is the best upper bound for $p_{n^2} - p_{(n-1)^2}$ ?!

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the best upper bound for $p_{n^2} - p_{(n-1)^2}$ ?!

Without any assumption, just proven facts and theorems, such that $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number.

I did numerical estimates and it suggest that its near $4 n \ln n$, is this true ?

Please help

Comment: [$n(\ln n+\ln \ln n)>p_n>n(\ln n+\ln \ln n-1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number)

Therefore $p_{n^2}<2n^2\ln(n)+\ln\ln n + \ln 2$ and $p_{(n-1)^2}>2(n-1)^2\ln(n-1)+\ln\ln(n-1)+\ln(2)-1$

From this we get that 

$$p_{n^2}-p_{(n-1)^2}\leq 2n^2\ln(n)+\ln\ln n -(2(n-1)^2\ln(n-1)+\ln\ln(n-1)-1)$$

Comment: @Marja That's an answer. See equation (15) here for a tighter bound. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit An asymptotic is not a bound.

Comment: @Marja this is a very bad upper bound, since there is a prime between $[x,x+x^{13/23}]$ we get that $p_{n^2}-p_{(n-1)^2} \leq 2 n n^{13/23}$ but i am looking for even better than this.

Comment: @Marja $n-1$ can become $n$ in this context, IMO

Answer (score 1):

I started from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number).

$p_n\approx n(\log n+\log \log n-1)$

And then computed

$p_{n^2}=n^2 \left(\log n^2+\log \log n^2-1\right)=n^2(2\log n+\log(2\log n)-1)=n^2(2\log n+\log 2+ \log\log n-1)$

and

$p_{(n-1)^2}=(n-1)^2 (2 \log (n-1)+\log (\log (n-1))-1+\log 2)$

Then I computed the difference, setting $n-1\to n$

$p_{n^2}-p_{(n-1)^2}\approx n+4 n \log n+2 n \log \log n-2 \log n$

With this estimation I got

$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n & \textit{extim.}&\textit{act.value}\\
\hline
 1000 & 32482 & 32970 \\
 11000 & 469504 & 476190 \\
 21000 & 953479 & 967430 \\
 31000 & 1458199 & 1475578 \\
 41000 & 1976631 & 2000468 \\
 51000 & 2505340 & 2528820 \\
 61000 & 3042273 & 3077556 \\
 71000 & 3586066 & 3627042 \\
 81000 & 4135741 & 4174020 \\
 91000 & 4690568 & 4745846 \\
\end{array}
$$

I think that it can be improved

Answer (score 0):

We have $p_n \sim n \ln(n)$ & $ \ln(n-1) \sim \ln(n)$. Form this one will rapidly obtain $p_{n^2}-p_{(n-1)^2} \sim 4n \ln n$. Use the following to obtain better approximation
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_n \sim n \ln n + n \ln( \ln n) -1 +\frac{ \ln (\ln n)-2}{ \ln n} -
\frac{(\ln (\ln n))^2-6 \ln (\ln n)+11}{ 2(\ln n)^2}+\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: it seems as approximation rather than upper bound ?!

Comment: You are right ... I will delete this answer, if you want.

Comment: it does not matter, but if you take $n(\ln n+\ln \ln n-1) < p_n < n(\ln +\ln \ln )$ so this give an upper bound which is $n^2 $, which is bad upper bound since there is a better bound $2 n n^{13/23}$.